# Exception "no ":" in url blackberry"

Tags: blackberry, java-me, j2mepolish

I am getting "no ":" in url blackberry" exception when I try to hit web service.
My url is like "http://url/MobileWrapper/action_name.do"

```
    String redemptionUrl = "http://test.TTMF.com/MobileWrapper/reconfirm.do";
HttpConnection httpConn = null; DataOutputStream dataOS = null;
redemptionUrl = redemptionUrl+ ";deviceside=true";
 httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(redemptionUrl);
```

Comment: show some snippet of code, otherwise its very difficult to know what is the problem??

Comment: String redemptionUrl = "http://test.TTMF.com/MobileWrapper/reconfirm.do"; HttpConnection httpConn = null;
   DataOutputStream dataOS = null;
   System.out.println("strModuleName.trim()::::"
     + strModuleName.trim());
   redemptionUrl = redemptionUrl+ ";deviceside=true";
   httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(redemptionUrl);

Comment: dont comment use edit to put your code... :)

Comment: try to put "http://" or something like that before redemptionUrl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your generated URL. It must be an invalid URL. Do debug or `System.out.print(..)`.

To make a connection you have to do some common tasks, such as

- White Space removal from URL.
- Encode unwanted characters in URL with their HTML equivalent code.
- Append appropriate connection parameter to the URL depending on connectivity support available on the device.